# CLI mod(root) dont accept login credentials on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: command-line, login, password

to install nvidia 304.64 driver on ubuntu 12.10 i need to login as root but it doeant accept my username and password and says incorrect login  i also has created a root password but still have the problem

what can I do ?

tnx

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to log on as root. As a matter of fact, this is a bad practice on which I will not lecture today other than mentioning that you should use the root account as little as possible. Make it a challenge for yourself to use it as little as possible.

What you should do is log on to the CLI with your regular account; the username you log on with to the GUI.

Then you have two options:

1. If you only need to type a few commands, type `sudo` in front of it. Eg: `sudo apt-get install mydriver`
2. If you *really* need to type a lot of commands as root, you can change to root user by typing `sudo -i`